# Setup issue with webpack, angular 2, css and sass

Tags: angular, sass, webpack-2

[UPDATED FROM ORIGINAL ISSUE] I am trying to setup the latest version of Angular2 with webpack to process sass.  I have scss files being processed now.  However, the problem is with css now.

I have added the following to the app.component.ts file...

```
require('../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
require('../../public/styles/styles.scss');
```

I am getting a build error from npm start...

```
    ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module build failed: ReferenceError: window is not defined
bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css doesn't export content
```

The relevant bits of webpack.common.js...

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ loader: [{ loader: "style-loader" }, { loader: "css-loader" } ] })
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ loader: [{ loader: "css-loader" }, { loader: "sass-loader" } ] })
  }
```

A snippet from my package.json...

```
"devDependencies": {
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
"@types/node": "^6.0.42",
"codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
"faker": "3.1.0",
"jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
"json-server": "0.9.4",
"karma": "1.2.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
"node-sass": "^4.4.0",
"protractor": "~4.0.13",
"raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
"sass-loader": "5.0.1",
"ts-node": "1.2.1",
"tslint": "4.3.0",
"typescript": "2.1.6",
"webdriver-manager": "11.1.1",
"angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.18",
"css-loader": "^0.26.1",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0-beta.5",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.16.1",
"file-loader": "^0.10.0",
"html-loader": "^0.4.3",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"postcss-loader": "1.2.2",
"webpack": "2.2.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "2.3.0",
"webpack-merge": "^2.6.1"
```

}

I have been trying to solve this for days.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I deleted my answer, try changing your configuration based on the plugin examples. https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader

Comment: Looking at the plugin examples, I changed my webpack config to {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          loader: [{
            loader: "css-loader"
          }, {
            loader: "sass-loader"
          }],
          fallbackLoader: "style-loader"
        })
      }       Now I get this error "Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings"    I have a component with this styleUrls: ['./invoice-list.component.scss'],  If I comment it out the error goes away

Comment: Hi Lee, install `raw-loader`, and use it before `css-loader`. That should sort out the issue with the `Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings`

Comment: added this and still getting the same error...{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          loader: [{
            loader: "raw-loader"
          },{
            loader: "css-loader"
          }, {
            loader: "sass-loader"
          }],
          fallbackLoader: "style-loader"
        })
      }

Comment: Could you try setting it up like I have below, and give that a go? Just as a process of elimination

Comment: Yes, just tried, get the same.  I am wondering if I have some other compatibility/syntax issue somewhere as these configurations do not seem to work for me but seem to be consistent with documentation I am finding

Comment: changed my component as follows which removed the error but still no styles applied to the page    @Component({
  templateUrl: './invoice-list.component.html',
  styles: ['./invoice-list.component.scss'],
  providers: [ InvoiceService, SortTableComponent ]
})

Comment: It might be worthwhile seeing if the styles are getting included or if they're just getting completely ignored. If you search for the selector for your component in the generated .js file. In my case I have this: `selector: 'cash-header',\n        styles: [__webpack_require__(611)],\n`. Search for the number 611 (or whatever it is in your instance) and see if it find css information for an associated function with that number is comments above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the answer.  It appears the angular docs are out of date, as well as webpack docs.

I ended up with this as my working config file...

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html']
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: [{
          loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
          options: { configFileName: helpers.root('src', 'tsconfig.json') }
        },
        'angular2-template-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ loader: [{ loader: "css-loader" }, { loader: "postcss-loader" } ]})
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ loader: [{ loader: "css-loader" }, { loader: "sass-loader" } ] })
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'css/[name].css', disable: false, allChunks: true }),
    // Workaround for angular/angular#11580
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
      helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

Then I added require statements to the app.component.ts file for the global css requirements, and then use the styles attribute on nested components for component specific styling.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that works for me with regards to the use of scss. It's important to note that I don't compile my resulting css into a separate file. It gets generated as a module in my resulting js file:

```
  {
    test: /\.(scss)$/,
    loaders: [
      'raw-loader',
      'sass-loader'
    ]
  }
```